# Filling vector-of-pairs with pair-of-pair not working as expected

Tags: c++, vector, std-pair, keyvaluepair

I have the following code that fills a vector containing pair of pairs.

```
std::vector<std::pair<double, std::pair<int, int>>> vec;
int x=100, y=10, z=20;
vec.push_back(std::make_pair((double)x,std::make_pair(y,z)));
for(int i=0;i<vec.size();i++){
    std::cout<<"x: "<<vec[i].first<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"y: "<<vec[i].second.first<<"\n";
    std::cout<<"z: "<<vec[i].second.second<<"\n";
}
```

The output:

```
x: 0
y: 0
z: 0
```

Why is it not printing as follows?

```
x: 100.0
y: 10
z: 20
```

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected. Tested with G++ compiler.
No issue observed.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    std::vector<std::pair<double, std::pair<int, int>>> vec;
    int x = 100, y = 10, z = 20;
    vec.push_back(std::make_pair((double)x, std::make_pair(y, z)));
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << "x: " << vec[i].first << "\n";
        std::cout << "y: " << vec[i].second.first << "\n";
        std::cout << "z: " << vec[i].second.second << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Please refer [this](https://www.ideone.com/85ZU1i) link